# Fish shell cd using relative path return: The directory “whatever” does not exist

Tags: shell, cd, fish

I'm having trouble with a basic behavior of `cd` in `fish` shell.

#### `cd` to relative directory

I'm willing to change directory using a relative path without the `./`. The directory exists:

```
❯ ls
addons/  custom-addons/  docker-compose.yml
```

The directory is auto-completed, yet I can't change to it:

```
❯ cd addons/
cd: The directory “addons/” does not exist
```

#### `CDPATH`

```
set -gx CDPATH $CDPATH $HOME/projects
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the documentation section [Special Variables](https://fishshell.com/docs/current#variables-special):

> `CDPATH`, an array of directories in which to search for the new
>   directory for the cd builtin. By default, the fish configuration
>   defines `CDPATH` to be a universal variable with the values `.` and `~`.

#### Diagnostic

I was overriding the default value while omitting `.` and `~` value.

#### Solution

Adding them back solved the issue, in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -gx CDPATH $CDPATH . ~ $HOME/projects
```

Then reload `fish` with:

```
exec fish
```